# How to check how many times an element exists in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
[5,6,7,2,4,8,5,2,3]
```

and I want to check how many times each element exists in this list.

what is the best way to do it in Python?

Answer (score 14):

The `count()` method counts the number of times an object appears in a list:

```
a = [5,6,7,2,4,8,5,2,3]
print a.count(5)  # prints 2
```

But if you're interested in the total of every object in the list, you could use the following code:

```
counts = {}
for n in a:
    counts[n] = counts.get(n, 0) + 1
print counts
```

Comment: Why is `total = counts.get(n,0)` included? I get the same result either way with, or without it, so it seems like an extra step.

Comment: You're right, it is a superfluous item. I'll edit to correct.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([5,6,7,2,4,8,5,2,3])
Counter({2: 2, 5: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}
```